# Node.js / Socket io video streaming does not seem to work while any other file type works

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Okay so i have the following route for when a file is being uploaded:

```
router.route('/moduleUpload')
.post(function (request, response) {
    request.files.file.originalname = request.files.file.originalname.replace(/ +?/g, '');
    var media = new Media(request.files.file, './user_resources/module/' + request.body.module_id + '/');
    if (!fs.existsSync(media.targetDir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(media.targetDir, 0777, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                response.send("ERROR! Can't make the directory! \n");    // echo the result back
            }
        });
    }
    moveFile(media);
    var token = jwt.encode({
        mediaObject: media
    }, require('../secret')());

    response.status(200).json(token);
});
```

As you can see this uses the support of a function called `moveFile(media);`

So here is that function:

```
    function moveFile(media) {
    var source = fs.createReadStream(media.file.path);
    var dest = fs.createWriteStream(media.targetDir + media.file.originalname);

    source.pipe(dest);
    source.on('end', function () { /* copied */
        console.log('file has been moved!')
    });
    source.on('error', function (err) { /* error */
        console.log('error while moving file')
    });
}
```

This works and the console prints out:

```
file has been moved!
```

Now after this i attempt to download / stream the video file i use the following route:

```
    router.route('/resource/:encodedString')
    .all(function (req, res) {
        var decoded = jwt.decode(req.params.encodedString, require('../secret')());
        var mediaObject = decoded.mediaObject;

        res.header('content-disposition', 'filename=' + mediaObject.file.originalname, "Content-Length: " + mediaObject.file.size, "mimeType:" + mediaObject.file.mimetype);
        var stream = fs.createReadStream(mediaObject.targetDir + mediaObject.file.originalname);
        stream.pipe(res);
        stream.on('end', function () {
            console.log("Reading operation completed.");
            res.end();
        });
    });
```

Using the encoded string i first decode it to find the media object and then stream it  back.

This works WITH EVERY file execpt mp4 / video files.

Here is the complete console print out of when i upload a video:

```
listening on *:8105
file has been moved!
Reading operation completed.
```

And here are my browser request headers:

```
    Remote Address:***
Request ****
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:5
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:Sun, 21 Jun 2015 17:13:24 GMT
Set-Cookie:io=1T7R1vmJ3xV-k0ApAABH
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:io=1T7R1vmJ3xV-k0ApAABH; lb_login_id=117
Host:angular.learningbankapp.com:8105
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/learningbankapp/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36
```

So can someone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does the file upload, in the first place?

Comment: @Bwaxxlo No errors in my console and the file is correctly uploaded

Comment: This looks like a problem with reading your file. How exactly do you read the files back to a browser? I usually add header like `res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "video/mp4"})` whenever I'm streaming a video. However, that might change depending on how you read/configure your files. Here's a [link with a sample video stream code](https://github.com/kdamball/NodeApp/blob/master/node_notes/test.js#L211)